# Is redis cache supported for embedded system

Tags: node.js, redis, embedded

Is redis cache supported for embedded systems like IOT smart devices where Node.js is deployed in Ostro OS along with 1GHz processor , 2GB RAM & 7MB Storage. Is there any system specification required for redis cache.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use Redis on IOT, but :

- you cannot store many data in memory (use Redis 32bits cause memory < 4GB),
- with 7MB Storage you can't persiste data on storage.

Regards